# Equivalent in R: stata tabplot (twoway barchart in tabular format)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a contingency table with ordinal data, and want to visualize this in R. I found a great solution presented here https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/148564, with the corresponding plot below. However, this was coded in Stata.

Is there any way to achieve this in R?

[image: tabplot]

Here is the data from the example presented in the link:

```
improvement  treatment   baseline   frequency  
       none          0       mild          5  
   moderate          0       mild         41  
substantial          0       mild          4  
       none          1       mild         19  
   moderate          1       mild         19  
substantial          1       mild         12  
       none          0   moderate         19  
   moderate          0   moderate         24  
substantial          0   moderate          7  
       none          1   moderate         20  
   moderate          1   moderate         14  
substantial          1   moderate         16  
       none          0     severe          7  
   moderate          0     severe         21  
substantial          0     severe         22  
       none          1     severe         12  
   moderate          1     severe         15  
substantial          1     severe         23
```

UPDATE: PoGibas' solved the problem with the example data above. But how to solve it without a frequency column? Both variables are factors.

```
Size  cDNA 
4     0    
2     3    
4     4    
2     3    
2     0    
2     1    
3     2    
3     3    
3     1    
4     1
```

Comment: Please  add example of your data (contingency table).

Comment: Please explain your data now - what should be grouped/on x-axis/on y-axis? It doesn't look like your primary dataset at all.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Size should be on the x-axis, there are 4 groups (1-4). An ordinal variable called cDNA should be the grouping on the y-axis. The bars should show frequencies/counts.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't still understand. Maybe something like this: `ggplot(d, aes(Size, cDNA, fill = factor(cDNA))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")`

Comment: Yes, that would be one way of showing it but then the bars are stacked together. I want the bars to be on shown in a grid just like in the example above. Just like the original plot above, but instead of "improvement" it should be grouped in "cDNA" categories (0-4). On the x-axis the bars should be grouped after the "Size" category.

Comment: It won't look nice, because: Not all sizes have same cDNA's. Before all "improvement" and "baseline" had "0" and "1". Now it's very different: `ggplot(d, aes(Size, cDNA)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    facet_wrap(~ cDNA)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(treatment))) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = frequency, alpha = rev(improvement)),
             stat = "identity", position = "dodge",
             color = "#209f1b", fill = "#35665C") +
    geom_text(aes(y = -5, label = frequency), color = "red") +
    facet_grid(improvement ~ baseline, switch = "both") +
    labs(title = "frequency",
         y = "improvement",
         x = "baseline and treatment") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 12),
          legend.position = "none")
```

To get result like this:

[image]

Explanation:

- `ggplot(df)` - passes your data (`df`) to `ggplot`
- `aes(factor(treatment))` - adds `treatment` on x-axis (as factor)
- `geom_bar` - creates barplot, where

  - `y = frequency` - we add `frequency` on y-axis
  - `alpha = rev(improvement))` - scales fill "shadiness" by `improvement` (it's reverse, because it goes from lightest to darkest)
- `geom_text(aes(y = -5, label = frequency)` - adds text (`frequency`) below (`-5`) bars

Data (`df`):

```
structure(list(improvement = c("none", "moderate", "substantial", 
"none", "moderate", "substantial", "none", "moderate", "substantial", 
"none", "moderate", "substantial", "none", "moderate", "substantial", 
"none", "moderate", "substantial"), treatment = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    baseline = c("mild", "mild", "mild", "mild", "mild", "mild", 
    "moderate", "moderate", "moderate", "moderate", "moderate", 
    "moderate", "severe", "severe", "severe", "severe", "severe", 
    "severe"), frequency = c(5L, 41L, 4L, 19L, 19L, 12L, 19L, 
    24L, 7L, 20L, 14L, 16L, 7L, 21L, 22L, 12L, 15L, 23L)), .Names = c("improvement", 
"treatment", "baseline", "frequency"), row.names = c(NA, -18L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you, that's excellent. Can I ask, how would you solve the problem if the data doesn't have the "frequency" column (everything else the same)? If it does not work, is there any easy way of calculating and adding such a column?

Comment: @zanyar So what kind of data you have? What's on y-axis? Please update your question with that information. From what I understand if it doesn't have "frequency" that everything is 1.