# Plotting two way bar chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following randomly created data:

```
t<- matrix(sample.int(100,size=20,replace=TRUE),nrow=12,ncol=20)

a = list()
b = list()
for (x in (1:20) ) b[[x]] <- paste0("X_", x)  
for (x in (1:12) ) a[[x]] <- paste0("X", x)  

row.names(t) <- rbind(a)
colnames(t)  <- rbind(b)

t <- as.data.frame(t)
```

Here `t` is a hypothetical two way table of frequencies, I am trying to plot a graph like the one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518315/equivalent-in-r-stata-tabplot-twoway-barchart-in-tabular-format) using ggplot2

I am not sure how can I make `t` in such a way that it can be used in ggplot2 code given in the link above. Also, I appreciate if you can provide suggestions on how to visualize a larger two way table, for instance, if dimension of `t` grows to something `30 x 50`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

EDIT to show values underneath:

```
t %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>%
  mutate(across(rowname:name, fct_inorder)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1, y = 0, label = value), vjust = 1.1, size = 2.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  facet_grid(rowname~name) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I am wondering if its possible to instead add the value between two vars, for example X1 and X_1, at the x-axis and remove y-axis labels in each bar?

Comment: Can you say more what you mean by "add the value between two vars"?

Comment: X1 and X_1 has for example a value 45, I want this value to appear at the x-axis of each bar, this is similar to the example shown in the link given in my question. Your solution shows y-scale in each bar, instead of the y-scale in each bar a single value as the x-axis perhaps would be more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update,  it looks nicer now. Could you please give suggestion(s), how this problem could be addressed if `t` grows in dimension?

Comment: That's a pretty subjective question that will depend upon what questions you're trying to answer. If you want to show 30 x 50 counts, that will involve 1,500 data points (and labels?!?), which would be difficult to distinguish. You might consider strategies like sorting the variables, or clustering into groups, or summarizing in some other way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modification of Jon Springs code with some "layout" tweaking:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>%
  mutate(across(rowname:name, fct_inorder)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = value, fill=value)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1, y = 0, label = value), vjust = 1.1, size = 2.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  facet_grid(rowname~name, switch = "both") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
        panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(0.2, "in"))+
  guides(fill="none")
```

[image]